# Passing multiple param values from view to controller in ERB form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, erb

I have a form:

```
<%= form_tag("index", method: "get") do %>
  <%= label_tag(:query, "Search for:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:query) %>

  <select>
    <%= options_for_select Species.all.collect{|sp| [sp.name, sp.id]}.insert(0, "Select Species") %>
  </select>

  <%= submit_tag("Search") %>
<% end %>
```

I can access `:query` in the controller via `params[:query]`. I want to be able to do the same with a dropdown menu from `options_select_for` when the form is submitted, i.e, access `params[:species]`.

I attempted doing something like this:

```
<%= :species, options_for_select Species.all.collect{|sp| [sp.name, sp.id]}.insert(0, "Select Species") %>
```

but Rails seems to dislike doing that and returns an error so I don't think that is the right syntax. How do I access multiple param values in my form?

This is the error:

```
Started GET "/proteins/index" for ::1 at 2015-08-21 12:11:52 -0700
Processing by ProteinsController#index as HTML
[]
  Rendered proteins/index.erb within layouts/application (2.0ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 11ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

SyntaxError (C:/Users/Shams/Documents/Overall/topfind4/topfind4.1/app/views/proteins/index.erb:18: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
...utput_buffer.append=( :species, options_for_select Species.a...
...                               ^):
  app/views/proteins/index.erb:18: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
```

I am using Rails 4.2 and Ruby 2.0.0.

Comment: will this help `<%= select_tag :species, options_for_select(Species.all.collect{|sp| [sp.name, sp.id]}, params[:species]), {prompty: "Select Species"} %> this way you will access like `params[:species]`
`

Comment: "returns an error", please copy and paste the error into your question. Do the same with any stack trace in your web server log.

Comment: This resulted in the dropdown menu's options to be written on the page and the dropdown menu becoming empty.

Comment: sorry after using the line in added in comment.? have you removed your `<select>` and `</select>`  after using my line.?

Comment: `Species.all.collect{|sp| [sp.name, sp.id]}.insert(0, "Select Species")` looks like code smell. You should do that in your controller, assign the result to a variable, and then access it in the view.

Comment: Sorry, I had not. I removed it and it works exactly how I wanted. Thanks +1

Comment: @theTinMan im hoping you wont mind that i incorporated your suggestion in my answer and also im thinking i have used that correctly. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove your own `<select>` tag and try using rails way like this

```
 <%= select_tag :species, options_for_select(Species.all.collect{|sp| [sp.name, sp.id]}, params[:species]), {prompt: "Select Species"} %>
```

Perhaps like the comment above suggested. Fetch all the species details you need in an array in `controller action` like this

```
@species_names = Species.pluck(:name, :id) #as per suggestion give in comment below
```

OR

```
@species_names = Species.all.collect{|sp| [sp.name, sp.id]}
```

and use that like this in view

```
<%= select_tag :species, options_for_select(@species_names, params[:species]), {prompt: "Select Species"} %>
```

This will much better approach.

Comment: Still a better approach would be using `Species.pluck(:name, :id)` instead of `Species.all.collect{|sp| [sp.name, sp.id]}`